# Getting list from a class returns as null

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a `public list` from another class, but when getting the list, it returns as null. When debugging, the list is being added to correctly, but it returns as null.

Here is my code:

**OrderAddToListWorkflow.cs**

```
Console.Clear();

OrderManager manager = OrderManagerFactory.Create();

Console.WriteLine("Add an Order");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Enter Order Number: ");
int orderNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter future date: ");
string date = Console.ReadLine();

OrderAddToListResponse newresponse = manager.ReadFile(orderNumber, date);
ProductsFile productsClassFile = new ProductsFile();
var myList = productsClassFile.productsFile.Select(x => x.ProductsFile).ToList(); //returns as null

Console.WriteLine("Enter Customer Name: ");
string customerName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter State: ");
string state = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter Tax Rate: ");
decimal taxRate = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myList[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine("Enter Product Type: ");
string productType = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter Area: ");
decimal area = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter Cost Per Square: ");
decimal costPerSquareFoot = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter Labor Cost Per Square Foot: ");
decimal laborCostPerSquareFoot = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

**ProductsFile.cs**

```
public List<Order> productsFile = new List<Order>();

    public void ReadFile()
    {
        string productsFileName = $"C:\\tempfolder\\Products.txt";
        List<string> productsLines = File.ReadAllLines(productsFileName).ToList();

        foreach (var productLine in productsLines.Skip(1))
        {
            List<string> entry = productLine.Split(',').ToList();

            Order productsOrder = new Order();
            productsOrder.ProductType = entry[0];
            decimal.TryParse(entry[1], out decimal _costPerSquareFoot);
            productsOrder.CostPerSquareFoot = _costPerSquareFoot;
            decimal.TryParse(entry[2], out decimal _laborCostPerSquareFoot);
            productsOrder.LaborCostPerSquareFoot = _laborCostPerSquareFoot;
            var _product = productsOrder.ProductsFile;

            productsFile.Add(productsOrder);
        }
    }
```

**Order.cs**

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public decimal Area { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPerSquareFoot { get; set; }
    public decimal LaborCostPerSquareFoot { get; set; }
    public decimal MaterialCost { get; set; }
    public decimal LaborCost { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }


    public string TaxFile => $"{State},{StateName},{TaxRate}";
    public string ProductsFile => $"{ProductType},{CostPerSquareFoot},{LaborCostPerSquareFoot}";

    public Order() { }
...
```

Here is one snapshot or debugging properties:

[image]

Here I see _orderRepository has the list of productsFile list.

[image]

But why can't I store ProductsFile which is a string type to a list?

[image]

Comment: In the last screenshot, you haven't executed the assignment yet. The watch window shows that `productsClassFile` and its `productsFile` field (should be a property, though) are both non-null; `Select` and `ToList` will never return null. Execute that line and `myList` will be assigned an instance.

Comment: I will check tomorrow. It didnt print anything.

Comment: It's clear, in the watch window, that `productsClassFile.productsFile` has no elements (evidenced by "Count = 0" in the "Value" column), so the resulting list could not possibly have any elements.

Comment: What's in your `ProductsFile` constructor? You're instantating it, and then immediately querying its (poorly-named) `.productsFile` property.

Comment: @3Dave I am expecting to pass those values to a string. My first time using it, not really sure if I am doing it right. I got this idea from IAmTimCory.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "pass those values to a string."

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it,
you are missing 
`productsClassFile.ReadFile();`

between

```
ProductsFile productsClassFile = new ProductsFile();
// insert here
var myList = productsClassFile.productsFile.Select(x => x.ProductsFile).ToList(); //returns as null
```

Comment: Ok  I am assusing you want me to call ReadFile() first within OrderAddToListworkflow.cs, but I am calling ReadFile() from another class, is there a reason for calling it there instead? Must not be the same.

Comment: It must be because when I say "new ProductsFile", its now empty.